# Bluetooth not working for Samsung phone when iPod connected via aux cable

Tags: bluetooth, samsung

Okay so my hands free Bluetooth connection works fine in my car for my galaxy 4 mini when playing CDs or radio. I can make and receive calls no problem at all. However when I connect my iPod via aux cable the phone stops connecting to the Bluetooth. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me it's the car that is disconnecting the bluetooth device when it detects an aux cable connection. If that's the case, you can try manually reconnecting with your Android phone.

If you can reconnect, then you could try setting up an automation schedule where the phone tries to reconnect to your car when that connection is lost.

If you cannot reconnect, your problem lies with the car. There may be a setting somewhere in the car settings that lets you keep bluetooth devices connected even if it detects an aux device. Or you may be out of luck; it's all dependent on the auto manufacturer's operating system.